# Returning Good Errors from UpdateDataSet

Tags: c#, database, dataset, prepared-statement, enterprise-library

**EDIT:** Solution (kind of)
So, what I did had very little in common with what I originally wanted to do, but my application now works *much* faster (DataSets that took upward of 15 minutes to process now go through in 30-40 seconds tops). Here's roughly what I did:
  - Read spreadsheet & populate `DataTable`/`DataSet` normally
  - [HACK WARNING] Instead of using UpdateDataSet, I generate my own SQL queries, mostly by having a skeleton string for each type of update (e.g. `String skeleton = "UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ..."`). I then consult the template database and replace the placeholder `...` with the appropriate entries.
  - [MORE HACK WARNING] The way I dealt with errors was by manually checking whether those errors will occur. So if I know I am about to do an insert, I'll run an error-checking command before the actual insert; what the error checker will do is construct a JOIN statement, checking whether any of the entries in the user's DataSet already exist in the database. Just by executing the JOIN command, I get back a DataSet with the results, so I know that if there is anything there, it's the errors. Then I can proceed to print them.

If anyone needs more details, I'll be happy to provide them. It's a fairly specific question, so I should probably keep this outline fairly high level.

**Original Question**
For (good) reasons outside of my control, I need to use the `Database.UpdateDataSet()` method from Microsoft's Enterprise Library. The way my project will work, I am letting the user make changes to the database (multiple database, multiple schemas, multiple tables, but always only one at a time) by uploading Excel spreadsheets to a web application. The spreadsheets follow a design/template specified by me (usually). I am a state where I read the spreadsheet, turn it into a DataTable/DataSet, and use (dynamically generated) prepared statements to make the appropriate changes to the database. Here's the problem:

Each spreadsheet only allows for one type of change (insert/update/delete). I want to make it so if the user uploads an insert spreadsheet, but several (let's say 10) of the entries are already in the database, I not only return with an error, but also tell them which entries (`DataRow`s) violated the primary key constraint.

The idea solution would be get a DataSet with the list of errors back, but I don't see how I can do that. Perhaps there is a way to construct the prepared statements in such a way that if a DataRow is to be inserted (following the example from above), it proceeds normally; however if it attempts to update or delete, it skips it and adds it to an error collection of some sort?

Note that I am trying to avoid using stored procedures. Since the number of different templates will grow extremely quickly after deployment, it is important that I stay away from manually written code and close to database-driven model as much as possible.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question? I am looking for the same, share if you have found a solution.

Comment: Afraid not. I had to take a step back and do half of the work manually (which actually made my application much faster). I am going to update my original post with an outline of what I did, maybe you'll find it useful.

Comment: Looking forward to it, might be of some help to me.

Comment: Go ahead and take a look. If it looks like this is something you want to do, we can move this conversation to emails and get into a greater level of detail there.

Comment: Although I am using stored procedures, I am validating my data before insertion and also checking foreign key constraints. Even after this if the update fails then the issue is not with the data. So I report the whole lot as a failure.